# FCKEditor - How to use the Save Icon on the toolbar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fckeditor

It's just my first dive on FCKEditor.  My simple question is how to use the Save icon on the toolbars, and my second question is how to remove/hide some of the toolbar icons?

I am using asp.net and c#.  Thanks.

Comment: I will never be able to get past the name of FCKEditor.  I used this on one project, and actually got a talking-to from my manager for using expletives in my code.  Dude needs to call this something else.

Answer (score 0):

for hiding or removing some icon, just open the file below and comment the icon that you don't want:

> \fckeditor\fckconfig.js

I am still looking on how to utilized SAVE Icon on the toolbar under asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to write your own code, because the editor is not supposed to know  how and where you save things. Here's my strategy on PHPBB-based [MFO forums](http://www.mrfixitonline.com/):

I disabled the save button and added [ajaxAutoSave mod](http://greenmap.sourceforge.net/fck_demo/about.html) which does both saving and autosaving. When a user saves (or autosaves) what he is working on, I save it in a special place on server. Each user has one, and he can get it back by going to "My latest draft" under Home menu. So, if your browser crashed in the middle of writing a long post, you can get it back. But, you cannot have more than one text saved.

Your strategy can be very different, it really depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic saving provided [here](http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API#Usage_Samples), but I can't seem to make it work yet.